# Привязка XAML кода UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Хай.
У меня есть страница на XAML и управляющий код на c#. В этой странице есть блок, его содержимое может изменятся в зависимости от событий, то есть необходимо в этот блок вставлять XAML код (он может быть прописан как в отдельном файле (оптимальный вариант), так и в string), на который тоже должен быть повешен управляемый код на C#.
Подскажите как это реализовать. Спасибо.

eg

```
namespace App5{
public sealed partial class Content : Page
{
    public Content()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do
    }
}}
```

Xaml:

```
<Page
  x:Class="App5.Content"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:App5"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">

   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <Button  Content="BUTTON" Click="Click"/>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

I need to insert this page into the block StackPanel Name="DataPage"

```
    <Page
      x:Class="App5.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App5"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Name="DataPage"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

При каком то событии, произошедшем на MainPage, все, что содержит страница content, должно вставиться в блок `<StackPanel Name="DataPage"/>`. В данном примере вставляется GRID с кнопкой. Необходимо не просто вставить содержимое, но и сохранить повешенное событие Click на кнопке.

Если кто знаком, то это как динамическая загрузка страниц на ajax (web), когда на странице есть статические элементы (меню, header, footer), а есть часть постоянно обновляющаяся (обычно это и есть сам контент страницы) при переходе по ссылке или при иных событиями.

Comment: Динамически генерировать объекты из XAML-кода можно с помощью [XamlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Потом достаточно просто задать DataContext и байндинги для получившегося объекта и вставить в дерево в коде.

Comment: Если не сложно, опишите изначальную задачу. потому что, то, что вы хотите сделать.... в общем вы не должны этого хотеть. И если задачу вам поставили именно так, то не связывайтесь с ними )

Comment: Скорее всего, вам нужен просто `UserControl`. Но да, лучше опишите свой конкретный случай. Сейчас ваш вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Непонятно снова. У вас есть главная страница, и страница `Content`. Эта вторая страница показывается отдельно, правильно? И на ней есть кнопка, по нажатию которой содержимое этой второй страницы должно попасть в главную страницу?

Comment: Еще раз дополнил

Comment: Может Вам нужны просто триггеры?

Comment: Я просто не понимаю, неужели это настолько экзотическая задача, что нужно танцевать с бубном? Неужели, если у тебя есть блок меню, который есть на всех страницах, то тебе придется копировать его код разметки на все страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с подобной ситуацией и решил его самым простым способом. Поставил статический bool член в отдельном классе и в MainPage кнопку, которая меняет значение этого члена. Когда true открывается одна страница, а когда false другая (или можно в коде страницы на c# настроить что выведется при том или и ном значении). и в MainPage контент на кнопке так же в зависимости от значения true/false.